# Width of a certain poset

Tags: order-theory

Define the poset $C_n=\langle \{1,2,\ldots,n\},\leq \rangle$. 
Do we have any single formula on the width of $C_n\times C_n\times C_n \times \ldots \times C_n$
where $\times$ is the direct product, and there are $m$ $C_n$s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a theorem of de Bruijn, Tengbergen and Kruyswijk, one antichain of
maximal size in a product of chains is those points at the "middle level".
Here the level of a point $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ will be $a_1+\cdots+a_m-m$
and the maximum level is $m(n-1)$. So the width will be the number of
solutions to
$$a_1+ \cdots +a_m -m =\left\lfloor\frac{m(n-1)}2\right\rfloor$$
for integers $a_i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Now what this number is, I don't know.

A reference for the theorem of de Bruijn, Tengbergen and Kruyswijk
is Ian Anderson's book *Combinatorics of Finite Sets*.

Comment: Is not the width simply the size of a maximal antichain?  For the problem that would be m, would it not?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes, the width is the size of a maximal antichain. No, that width is not $m$.

Comment: Would you give an example when width > m for the smallest value of m such an example is possible?

Comment: @WilliamElliot For $C_n\times C_n$ ($m=2$) the width is $n$.